# Java String format error

Tags: java, string

for some reason this string format is not working. It says that frameCount should be an object. I'm not importing any libraries at the moment. Does anyone know why it gives an error?

frameRate is a String, frameCount is an int

```
frameRate = String.format("FPS %s", frameCount);
```

Answer (score 2):

`%s` is the placeholder for a String use `%d` instead.

`String.format()` is also the slowest way to build Strings. Use a Stringbuilder or for simple cases just the `+` operator.

`frameRate = "FPS " + frameCount;`

Comment: String.format on the other hand can lead to cleaner code and enable easy extracting of strings for translation. Unless speed is important and String.format was determined to be the bottleneck (using a profiler) i wouldn't care about the speed aspect.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind I agree with you when it comes to more complex Strings than in the case described by op. In his case I would just go with the faster method because both methods are identical from a copy quality perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to print an int?
Instead of :

```
frameRate = String.format("FPS %s", frameCount);
```

Change it to:

```
frameRate = String.format("FPS %d", frameCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

use: `frameRate = String.format("FPS %d", frameCount);`

`%d` stands for a digit `%s` is a String

Read the documentation about [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the appropriate placehodler for `int` primitives which is `%d`:

```
frameRate = String.format("FPS %d", frameCount);
```

Or keep the current formatting rule and convert the `int` `frameCount` to a String to fit in the `%s` placeholder:

```
frameRate = String.format("FPS %s", String.valueOf(frameCount)); //Useless overhead
```

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you're using an old version of Java (pre-1.5) where parameters were not automatically autoboxed. Correcting the format specifier, you could use

```
frameRate = String.format("FPS %d", frameCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep `frameCount` as an integer (because of requirement), you can convert it to string, but this will unnecessarily increase one step and code performance will be degraded.

```
frameRate = String.format("FPS %s", String.valueOf(frameCount));
```